# Difference between two strings with time and weekday

Tags: php, mysql

I have two times saved in database as

```
DayTime1 = "Wed 09:00"
DayTime2 = "Wed 13:00"
```

I want to get the difference between these two dates in minutes.

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTES,DayTime1,DayTime2) return null
```

I'm not able to get through it. Is there any way to get difference?

Comment: what is the datatype of DayTime1 and DayTime2 ?

Comment: Why do this in MySQL?

Comment: Your specs are kind of vague. Let's say today it's Wednesday. What'd be the expected output of `'Tue 23:50' - 'Wed 00:10'`? 20? -20? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note, that `SELECT STR_TO_DATE("Wed 09:00", "%a %H:%i")` returns **`0000-00-00`** `09:00:00` (at least on my local MySql 5.5.16). So if comparing different days, you won't get the correct result.

If given a year and week, the day name will be interpreted to a real date, so comparisons may also span days. For example (though not really elegant, I admit):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE()), ' Tue 09:00'), '%x%v %a %H:%i'),
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), WEEKOFYEAR(CURDATE()), ' Wed 13:00'), '%x%v %a %H:%i')
)
```

Comment: @Parikshit.S.Shekhawat May I suggest you edit the question and explain what result you expect so all this can help others?

Answer (score 2):

Since you also included the `php`-tag, I'm assuming a PHP solution is valid as well:

```
$daytime1 = "Wed 09:00";
$daytime2 = "Wed 13:00";
$diff = abs(strtotime($daytime1) - strtotime($daytime2)); //absolute diff in seconds
$diff = $diff / 60; //Difference in minutes
```

**EDIT:**

And here is a pure MySQL solution:

```
SELECT ABS(
    TIME_TO_SEC(
        TIMEDIFF(
            STR_TO_DATE("Wed 09:00", "%a %H:%i"),
            STR_TO_DATE("Wed 13:00", "%a %H:%i")
        )
    )
) / 60
```

The second parameter, `"%a %H:%i"`is the date format. If it's always in the format of "First three letters of weekday, space, hour with leading zero, `:`, minutes" then you can use this format.

Comment: Please note that a string with yesterday's weekday will return *next* day that corresponds to such weekday rather than yesterday. It might be what the OP wants or not.